# How to find a string and replace part of it using batch commands?

Tags: batch-file

I have text file with lot of parameters with unique names. I need to find a parameter by its name and change the value of the parameter. The file looks something like this

```
   ID      Value          Name
  4450     2.0        / [var_pot] 'DCF_loc'
  4451     100.0      / [var] 'DCF_t'
  4452     0.1        / [var] 'DCF_dur'
  4458     1000.0     / [var] 'CommtF_t_P1'
```

For e.g. I need to find the parameter 'DCF_t' in the file and replace its value from 100 to some other value say 10. Unfortunately in my case, only the names and values of the parameters are in my control. I am in need of a batch file to do the "find and replace" job.

Please help me out...Thanks in advance...

Comment: so what you are saying is that for id 4452 value should be 10? identified by DCF_t? what scripting languages are available? php/bash/perl/python/c?

Comment: is that windows or what?

Comment: @jancha- yeah, you got it correct and preferable language would be MS-DOS batch script

Answer (score 2):

in case it is Windows, you need to

1. loop over all the lines of the file. try something like.. `FOR /F %%a in (values.txt) DO echo %%a`
2. skip the first header line. Try `FOR /f "skip=1" %%a in (%1) do echo %%a`
3. parse the contents of the line. Try `FOR /f "skip=1 tokens=1-5" %%a in (%1) do echo %%b %%d`
4. check the fourth item. Try

   ```
   for /f "skip=1 tokens=1-5" %%a in (%1) do (
     if /i .%%e.==.'DCF_t'. (
       echo %%a  99.9  %%c  %%d  %%e
     ) else (
       echo %%a  %%b  %%c  %%d  %%e
     )
   )
   ```

and you almost done, or at least in your way to the solution.  See `HELP FOR` and `HELP IF` for more information.

Comment: You win the race :-), but you can't skip lines, as the OP needs a modified file not only a single line

Comment: it's not intented to be a complete final solution, just an example on how to proceed. There are still other pending problems, as they are not clear in the OP text; for example, how to format the resulting line, what to do with blank chars, what if the original text has more items than 5, what if the original text contains substrings DCF_t .. and many more. OP need to put effort either in implementing the solution or in the writing of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit cryptic for batch beginners. And there are many better languages to do this job.
But it can be done also with batch.

The key is to rewrite the file and modify the correct line.

```
set "otherValue=10"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(
  For /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%a in (myFile.txt) do (
    set "var=%%c"
    if "!var!"=="!var:DCF_t=!" (
      rem ** not found, echo the line
      echo(%%a %%b !var!
    ) ELSE (
      rem ** Found the line
      echo(%%a %otherValue% !var!
    )
  )
) > outfile.txt
```

This assumes, that there are no exclamation marks in the text and that the lines are formatted always into three parts delimited by spaces or tabs.